# What is known about the area of the symmetric Pythagorean tree?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, fractals

What is known about the area of the symmetric [Pythagorean tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_%28fractal%29)?  (Closed unit square as base, area of enclosed triangles not included.)  The problem in calculating the area is that squares start to overlap from the sixth iteration onwards.

Without much effort it can be computed that height is 4 and breadth is 6, so an upper bound for the area is 24.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_%28fractal%29#Area) reports that lower and upper bounds can with some effort be tightened to 5 and 18, respectively.  The accompanying [Wikipedia talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Pythagoras_tree_%28fractal%29) page reports on numerical approximations (pixel counts) that end somewhere near 14.  Other than that, no trace of a hint of an exact answer in the literature.

Seems like a simple high-school  problem.  On closer inspection I believe it is not, due to the problem of overlapping squares.

Comment: What is a symmetric Pythagorean tree?

Comment: My guess: take a unit square, adjoin a right triangle so that hypotenuse identified with side of square.  Call this pentagon P.  Now attach two scaled pentagons similar to P to each leg of the triangle part of P.  Repeat in a fractal fashion; rest of specification left to you.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.05.03

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_(fractal) $\:$

Comment: "My guess".  Wrong guess, do to neglect of overlap.

Comment: @Ricky: thanks for the link. @Gerard: Wrong guess, due to lack of wikipedia link.

Comment: Okay, incorporated link.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: I reiterate Anton's (trollish?!) question. I think this question should be closed unless it is edited. From the FAQ: "MathOverflow is not the right place to ask open problems. You should post questions you're actually seriously thinking about. If you're thinking about a well-known open problem, provide some background and ask about something specific related to the problem."

Comment: Mathematics has a huge collection of beautiful problems, and a much smaller collection of researchers, so a problem has to justify itself with some evidence of being closely connected to major advances or major research programmes in order to command attention. It is easy to become fascinated by a problem, but very hard to communicate to others why they should put down their problems and pay attention to yours. I would like more evidence first that this is a good problem before I start looking at it. Of course, such evidence is never very solid; solid evidence shows up only when we solve it.

Comment: I would like to see a more civil response to Anton's question. His question is one that mathematicians ask each other all the time when told of an unfamiliar question or theorem. It deserves a real answer. Until then, I vote to close.

Comment: Definitely the question should be edited to include a precise definition of the Pythagorean tree, at least.

Comment: I don't know, guys. The linked Wikipedia article seems to give a clear enough indication of what the (symmetric) Pythagorean tree is; just click on it if you want to know. If the question were slightly edited to "what is known about the area?" (beyond what is contained in the Wikipedia article or articles linked therein), then it wouldn't disqualify itself on the grounds of being an open problem, and probably about as acceptable as many other MO questions, although I agree with Deane that the response to Anton was really uncalled for (and could warrant a flag). If you don't like it, skip it. 

Comment: Why I do care?  Because it is a challenging problem I am thinking about for a long while, got no further, and decided to share.  Simple.

Comment: If you look at the Talk page attached to the Wikipedia article, someone did some numerical approximations, and found that the area is a little less than 14.

Comment: @Gerard: such a *pro tem* explanation is good enough for me. It would be ridiculous to hold every MO question to the same standard (explain to me why I should care), and in my view many other questions that appear on MO are of even less intrinsic interest. I expect the problem is indeed challenging. People should work on it only if they feel like it. 


Comment: A belated response to Anton et al: Overlaps are very important in fractal geometry: Dimension theorems of self-similar sets and the like mostly involve separation conditions to avoid overlaps; interesting stuff, often number theoretic, happens when these conditions are violated.